# c++: why template cannot be used to deduce both container and element type?

Tags: c++, class, templates, containers, typename

I've got a very simple test program like below:

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename C, typename E>
void f(const C<E>& container){
    cout<<container.size()<<endl;
}
int main(){
    vector<int> i;
    f(i);
    return 0;
}
```

It fails to compile with gcc 4.1.2. Error message is:

```
templateContainer.cpp:5: error: ‘C’ is not a template
templateContainer.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
templateContainer.cpp:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘f(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)’
```

Comment: That's why containers have *associated type*. You don't need `E`; just write `typename C::value_type` (or `typename C::reference_type` as appropriate).

Comment: To clarify, the error message is because `C` is **defined** as the name of a type (`typename C`), but it's **used** as the name of a template (`C<E>`). It can't be both.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a *template template parameter* (and note that `std::vector` actually takes more than one template parameter [an element type, and an allocator type]).:

```
template<template <typename...> class C, typename... E>
void f(const C<E...>& container){
    cout<<container.size()<<endl;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32d2ff856c674a8d)

---

If you don't need the type decompositions, you could simply use an ordinary template.

```
template<typename C>
void f(const C& container){
    cout<<container.size()<<endl;
}
```

You can additionally obtain typedefs from STL containers: for example, if you want to know the *type* of elements held by the container, `value_type` is there for you.

```
template<typename C>
void f(const C& container){
    using ValueType = typename C::value_type;
    cout<<container.size()<<endl;
}
```

Comment: without variadic templates (ie C++11) one would need to know the number of parameters in advance?

Comment: @tobi303, Yep, Otherwise, some old unpleasant trick of overloading with many many template parameters

Comment: Note that while this is definitely correct answer to the question as stated, if you actually use it to deduce the value type of a container, you deserve to be fired on the spot. Containers have typedefs for the associated types and you should always use those. Because the container contract requires those and does *not* require the value type to be a template argument at all.

Answer (score 2):

std::vector has two template arguments, type and allocator.

```
template <template<class, class> class C, class E, class A>
void f(const C<E, A> &container) 
{
   std::cout << container.size() << endl;
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> i;
   f(i);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although WhiZTiM's answer is correct (well, preferring the second part), it doesn't explain *why* your code doesn't work.

Assuming for the moment that you intended roughly

```
template<template <typename> class C, typename E> void f(const C<E>&);
```

the reason that `std::vector` doesn't match is that it is the wrong shape - it has two type parameters, not one as in your declaration.

Just because you don't often *explicitly* write the defaulted second (allocator) param, doesn't mean it isn't there.

For comparison, this works (or doesn't) in an analogous way:

```
void f(int);
void g(int, int* = nullptr);

void apply(void (*func)(int), int);

apply(f, 42); // ok - f matches shape void(*)(int)
apply(g, 42); // error - g is really void(*)(int,int*)
```

specifically, default arguments (or type parameters) are syntactic sugar. They allow you to forget about those arguments at the call (instantiation) site, but don't change the shape of the function (or template).